# How can we tell non Muslim male guests to be wary of urine drops?

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim, taharah, muslim-practices, najis

In Islam, men should sit down to pass water (urinate) as this avoids urine sprinkles / droplets going on the clothes, body, seat and floor.

We aren't accustomed to cleaning up urine except for small kids, disabled, sick, the incontinent or elderly people who may find it hard to be so careful.

***If we have non Muslim males as guests or workmen / tradesmen how do we explain them to be extra careful or even sit down in an intelligent, tactful and non offensive way?*** Or it's not possible?

Comment: Why aren't you accustomed to cleaning up ... isn't Islam asking us to keep clean? It is your duty to keep yourself and your clothes in a state of tahara you may find different options so this question has no focused answer and is opinion-based (off-topic).